# ¿Cómo sincronizo las salidas de dos procesos usando un semáforo con C en Linux?

Tags: c, linux

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SEMAFORO 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int semid, pid, j = 10;
    struct sembuf operacion;
    key_t llave;

    llave = ftok(argv[0], 'U');

    if ((semid = semget(llave, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0600)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error al ejecutar semget");
        exit(-1);
    }
    semctl(semid, SEMAFORO, SETVAL, 1);

    /* Se crea el proceso hijo  */
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error al ejecutar fork");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        /* Codigo correspondiente al proceso hijo  */
        while (j)
        {
            /* Se realiza la operacion DOWN en el semaforo  */
            operacion.sem_flg = 0;
            operacion.sem_op = -1;
            operacion.sem_num = SEMAFORO;

            semop(semid, &operacion, 1);

            printf("SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: %d\n", j--);

            /* Se realiza la operacion UP en el semaforo  */
            operacion.sem_op = 1;
            operacion.sem_num = SEMAFORO;
            semop(semid, &operacion, 1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* Codigo correspondiente al proceso padre */
        while (j)
        {
            /* Se realiza la operacion DOWN en el semaforo */
            operacion.sem_flg = 0;
            operacion.sem_op = -1;
            operacion.sem_num = SEMAFORO;

            semop(semid, &operacion, 1);

            printf("SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: %d\n", j--);

            /* Se realiza la operacion UP en el semaforo */
            operacion.sem_op = 1;
            operacion.sem_num = SEMAFORO;
            semop(semid, &operacion, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Por lo que podría esperar la siguiente salida:

```
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 10
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 10
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 9
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 9
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 8
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 8
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 7
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 7
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 6
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 6
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 5
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 5
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 4
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 4
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 3
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 3
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 2
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 2
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 1
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 1
```

O primero el hijo y después el padre sucesivamente. Sin embargo, lo ejecuto y la salida que me produce es la siguiente:

```
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 10
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 9
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 8
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 7
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 6
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 5
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 4
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 3
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 2
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 1
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 10
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 9
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 8
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 7
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 6
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 5
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 4
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 3
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 2
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 1
```

O aveces sale esta impresión, pero no me sale la esperada:

```
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 10
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 9
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 10
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 9
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 8
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 7
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 6
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 5
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 8
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 7
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 6
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 4
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 3
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 2
SOY EL PROCESO HIJO, IMPRESION: 1
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 5
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 4
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 3
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 2
SOY EL PROCESO PADRE, IMPRESION: 1
```

Entiendo que el orden de ejecución de los procesos depende directamente del sistema operativo, pero ¿No se supone que cuando uno de los dos procesos haga UP, deberia de entrar el otro a ejecutarse?

Así que mi duda es, ¿qué esta pasando aquí exactamente?

Comment: Hola. He ejecutado tu código muchas veces ... y **siempre** muestra la salida esperada O_O

Comment: ¿¡En serio!? :0 ¿Que Sistema operativo usaste? .-.

Comment: Ubuntu Eoan, Kernel 5.3.0-42-generic, gcc 9.2.1 20191008, libc6 2.30-0ubuntu2.1